# Stuck on "unique key" warning

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm currently adapting a Mobx tutorial for a to-do app. [link](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-with-mobx-getting-started-ba7e18d8ff44)
What I want to do is add a simple counter button to each rendered list item. I figured this would be pretty simple, but I must be making a syntactical error because I cannot get things to mesh properly. The main error I'm getting right now is that "Each child in an array or iterator must have a unique 'key' property". I figured I would solve this by adding in a uuid to each counter(the counter is what cause the error to begin appearing). Alas, I cannot seem to find a solution.

Here is the github repository for the app: https://github.com/Darthmaul/UmCount

Specifically [this file](https://github.com/Darthmaul/UmCount/blob/master/app/newItem.js) is the one that has received the most modifications. I also added a "counterstore.js" file to keep the store of the counter intact(which seems to be failing).

Any help would be appreciated. At this point I just don't know what's wrong and what's right.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: You should add the code which you believe is causing the issue directly to the question instead of linking it. Links can break, and SO answers are meant to be useful for anyone who experiences the same issue, even years later. Also, it just makes it plain easier for people to answer you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a component which has an array of children, each of which might have its own children, not only the top-level children but also each child at a deeper level needs its own key.

The problem with doing

```js
const Items = ({items}) => (
  <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 10}}>
   {items.map((item, i) => {
        return (<View>
          <Text style={styles.item} key={i}>• {item} - {store.counter}</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => store.increment()} title="+1" color="#50EB5D" key={uuid()} />
          </View>
        )})
    }
  </View>
)
```

is that your `Text` and `Button` components have keys, but your `View`s do not.

React uses keys for reconciliation and finding the minimal change whenever a list of components changes. How you set keys here will affect the reconciliation policy when your array changes: You can set your `View`, `Text` and `Button` for each array element to have the same key if you know that whenever one of them changes, the entire row changes, but if each of them changes separately, then you should generate a unique ID for each of them.

[React docs on reconciliation and keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

Comment: Thank you, I had completely overlooked the view the whole time. Did not realize that EVERY component needed a key!